# Parse URL (ActionScript 3.0)

Tags: actionscript-3, url

I would like to know how would one parse an URL.

protocol://mydomain.com/something/morethings/this_is_what_i_want/even_if_it_has_slashes

I need to get "this_is_what_i_want/even_if_it_has_slashes"

How should I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi - Can you add some context to the problem you're trying to solve? I.e. Is this the URL coming from the browser or input from a form? Do you only ALWAYS need the last two parameters in the URL path?

Comment: Hello, it will come from the browser.
I always need everything that comes after "something" (note that something will be dynamic)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be a little more flexible in the feature (e.g. you need the domain), you can use my Url class.

**Class for URL parsing**

```
package
{
    import flash.net.URLVariables;

    public class Url
    {
        protected var protocol:String = "";
        protected var domain:String = "";
        protected var port:int = 0;
        protected var path:String = "";
        protected var parameters:URLVariables;
        protected var bookmark:String = "";

        public function Url(url:String)
        {
            this.init(url);
        }

        protected function splitSingle(value:String, c:String):Object
        {
            var temp:Object = {first: value, second: ""};

            var pos:int = value.indexOf(c);
            if (pos > 0)
            {
                temp.first = value.substring(0, pos);
                temp.second = value.substring(pos + 1);
            }

            return temp;
        }

        protected function rtrim(value:String, c:String):String
        {
            while (value.substr(-1, 1) == c)
            {
                value = value.substr(0, -1);
            }

            return value;
        }

        protected function init(url:String):void
        {
            var o:Object;

            var urlExp:RegExp = /([a-z]+):\/\/(.+)/
            var urlPart:Array = urlExp.exec(url);
            var temp:Array;
            var rest:String;

            if (urlPart.length <= 1)
            {
                throw new Error("invalid url");
            }

            this.protocol = urlPart[1];
            rest = urlPart[2];

            o = this.splitSingle(rest, "#");
            this.bookmark = o.second;
            rest = o.first;

            o = this.splitSingle(rest, "?");
            o.second = this.rtrim(o.second, "&");

            this.parameters = new URLVariables();
            if (o.second != "")
            {
                try
                {
                    this.parameters.decode(o.second);
                }
                catch (e:Error)
                {
                    trace("Warning: cannot decode URL parameters. " + e.message + " " + o.second);
                }
            }
            rest = o.first

            o = this.splitSingle(rest, "/");
            if (o.second != "")
            {
                this.path = "/" + o.second;
            }
            rest = o.first;

            o = this.splitSingle(rest, ":");
            if (o.second != "")
            {
                this.port = parseInt(o.second);
            }
            else
            {
                switch (this.protocol)
                {
                case "https": 
                    this.port = 443;
                    break;
                case "http": 
                    this.port = 80;
                    break;
                case "ssh": 
                    this.port = 22;
                    break;
                case "ftp": 
                    this.port = 21;
                    break;
                default: 
                    this.port = 0;
                }
            }
            this.domain = o.first;
        }

        public function getDomain():String
        {
            return this.domain;
        }

        public function getProtocol():String
        {
            return this.protocol;
        }

        public function getPath():String
        {
            return this.path;
        }

        public function getPort():int
        {
            return this.port;
        }

        public function getBookmark():String
        {
            return this.bookmark;
        }

        public function getParameters():URLVariables
        {
            return this.parameters;
        }
    }
}
```

**Example usage**

```
try {
    var myUrl:Url = new Url("protocol://mydomain.com/something/morethings/this_is_what_i_want/even_if_it_has_slashes");

    trace("Protocol: " + myUrl.getProtocol());
    trace("Domain: " + myUrl.getDomain());
    trace("Path: " + myUrl.getPath());
    trace("What you want: " + myUrl.getPath().split("/").splice(2).join("/") );

} catch (e:Error) {
    trace("Warning: cannot parse url");
}
```

**Output**

```
Protocol: protocol
Domain: mydomain.com
Path: /something/morethings/this_is_what_i_want/even_if_it_has_slashes
What you want: morethings/this_is_what_i_want/even_if_it_has_slashes
```

**Description**

1. The init function checks with the regular expression if the given url starts with some letters (the protocol) followed by a colon, two slashes and more characters.
2. If the url contains a hash letter, everything behind its fist occurrence is taken as a bookmark
3. If the url contains a question mark, everything behind its fist occurrence is taken as key=value variables and parsed by the URLVariables class.
4. If the url contains a slash, everything behind its first occurrence is taken as the path
5. If the rest (everything between the last protocol slash and the first slash of the path) contains a colon, everything behind it will be converted to an integer and taken as the port. If the port is not set, a default will be set in dependency of the protocol
6. The rest is the domain
7. For answering your question, I use the path of the given url, split it by slash, cut of the 'something' and join it by slash.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
var u:String = 'protocol://mydomain.com/something/morethings/this_is_what_i_want/even_if_it_has_slashes',
    a:Array = u.split('/'),
    s:String = ''

for(var i=0; i<a.length; i++){  
    if(i > 3){
        s += '/'+a[i]
    }   
}

trace(s) // gives : /morethings/this_is_what_i_want/even_if_it_has_slashes
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be using Regex like this:

```
.*?mydomain\.com[^\/]*\/[^\/]+\/[^\/]+\/([^?]*)
```

([Breakdown of the components.](http://www.regexper.com/#.*%3Fmydomain%5C.com%5B%5E%5C%2F%5D*%5C%2F%5B%5E%5C%2F%5D%2B%5C%2F%5B%5E%5C%2F%5D%2B%5C%2F(%5B%5E%3F%5D*)))

This looks for a pattern where it skips whatever comes before the domain name (doesn't matter if the protocol is specified or not), skips the domain name + TLD, skips any port number, and skips the first two sub path elements. It then selects whatever comes after it but skips any query strings.

Example: http://regexr.com/39r69

In your code, you could use it like this:

```
var url:String = "protocol://mydomain.com/something/morethings/this_is_what_i_want/even_if_it_has_slashes";
var urlExp:RegExp = /.*?mydomain\.com[^\/]*\/[^\/]+\/[^\/]+\/([^?]*)/g;
var urlPart:Array = urlExp.exec(url);
if (urlPart.length > 1) {
    trace(urlPart[1]);
    // Prints "this_is_what_i_want/even_if_it_has_slashes"
} else {
    // No matching part of the url found
}
```

As you can see on the regexr link above, this captures the part "**this_is_what_i_want/even_if_it_has_slashes**" for all of these variations of the url:

```
protocol://mydomain.com/something/morethings/this_is_what_i_want/even_if_it_has_slashes
protocol://mydomain.com:8080/something/morethings/this_is_what_i_want/even_if_it_has_slashes
protocol://mydomain.com/something/morethings/this_is_what_i_want/even_if_it_has_slashes.html
protocol://mydomain.com/something/morethings/this_is_what_i_want/even_if_it_has_slashes.html?hello=world
mydomain.com/something/morethings/this_is_what_i_want/even_if_it_has_slashes
protocol://subdomain.mydomain.com:8080/something/morethings/this_is_what_i_want/even_if_it_has_slashes
```

Edit: Fixed typo in regexp string

Answer (score 0):

Simple way,

```
    var file:String = 'protocol://mydomain.com/something/morethings/this_is_what_i_want/even_if_it_has_slashes';
    var splitted:Array = file.split('/');
    var str1:String = splitted.splice(3).join('/'); //returns 'something/morethings/this_is_what_i_want/even_if_it_has_slashes'
    var str1:String = splitted.splice(5).join('/'); //returns 'this_is_what_i_want/even_if_it_has_slashes'
```